# beq command not jumping to a label in MIPS

Tags: command, mips, mars-simulator

I am creating a MIPS code in MARS that allows only an input of a numerical expression, and print an error message when characters other than numbers, +,-,*, and / are present.

In my following code, I set $s0 to zero if there is an invalid character, otherwise it stays at 1. If it is equal to zero, using the beq command I would jump to "erroneous" which handles the error message.

However, that last part does not seem to happen. If you run my code you'll see that it actually gets the proper values of $s0 right (that is, if the expression is invalid, it becomes equal to 0).

I need a fresh set of eyes, I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
.data 
input: .space 102
trial: .asciiz "LOLLOL\n"
errormsg: .asciiz "ERROR\n"
.text

main:
addi $v0, $zero, 8
la $a0, input
addi $a1, $a0, 102
syscall
addi $t1 , $zero, 0
add $s1, $zero, $zero
addi $a0, $zero, -1
addi $s0, $zero,1

check_invalid_char_1:
#beq $s0, $s1, erroneous
jal check_invalid_char
j allowed

check_invalid_char:
addi $sp,$sp,-8
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)
#sw $v0, 8($sp)

addi $a0, $a0,1
addi $t3, $zero,0
beq $s0, $zero, erroneous

lb $t2, input($a0)
beq $t2, 48, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 0
beq $t2, 49, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 1
beq $t2, 50, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 2
beq $t2, 51, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 3
beq $t2, 52, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 4
beq $t2, 53, check_invalid_char_1       #pwede 5
beq $t2, 54, check_invalid_char_1       #pwede 6
beq $t2, 55, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 7
beq $t2, 56, check_invalid_char_1       #pwede 8
beq $t2, 57, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede 9
beq $t2, 43, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede +
beq $t2, 45, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede -
beq $t2, 42, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede *
beq $t2, 47, check_invalid_char_1   #pwede /
beq $t2, 0, allowed             #pwede null terminator
beq $t2, 10, allowed            #pwede newline


add $s0, $zero,$zero

lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $a0, 4($sp)
#lw $v0, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8

jr $ra


erroneous:
#add $a0, $zero, $zero
la $a0, errormsg
addi $v0, $zero, 4
syscall


allowed:
addi $v0, $zero, 1
add $a0, $s0, $zero
syscall
#la $a0, errormsg
#addi $v0, $zero, 4
#syscall
addi $v0, $zero, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who may encounter this question, I may have solved my own problem, but I am not sure if it is really a fix, or a "cheat". It's more of a work around really.

I moved the "beq $s0, $zero, erroneous" line to the "allowed:" label. I don't know why it doesn't work from inside check_valid_char, but it works.

Then inside erroneous, I reset $s0 to 0 by using "sub $s0, $s0, $s0" so that when the code goes again to allowed: , beq will just be skipped and it will end normally.

If others can find a "real" solution for my problem, please post that.

Thanks!

edit: some punctuations.